# Why did a technician jump W to G on my furnace?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace

I have a York diamond 80 furnace and the control board burned out so Lowe’s came and replaced it. I’ve been using the heater because it’s winter right now but the other day I accidentally hit the cool button on my thermostat and it sounded like something popped so I checked it out the wiring and realized the 3A fuse blew out. But I noticed that the thermostat wiring is different from before Lowe’s installed the new motherboard.

The thermostat has (W with W) (G with G) (Y with Y) (R with RC) as it should because they never touched the thermostat but on the control board of the furnace which is the part that Lowe’s switched out they have (W and G) jumped  together and the rest of the colors match with the thermostat before they installed that control board. I knew that W was by itself and G was by itself. I don’t know why they would jump W with G together but can that cause my unit to be faulty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "they have (W and G) jumped together" - I'm not seeing that. All I'm seeing is the green not hooked to your furnace, and the blue is on the G terminal at the T-stat for some reason. What's it say behind the green wire? OT SEL ?

Comment: What make and model is your thermostat?

Comment: They put the blue in the (G) section on the thermostat but the motherboard the (G) is connected with the (C) I thought those had to be separated that’s why the motherboard has a section for (G)?

Comment: On the thermostat the green wire is connected to (not used)

Comment: I don’t know what the model of the thermostat is

Comment: I would verify functionality and call lowes as it should have been exchanged wire for wire! 
Many hvac systems are not wired to traditional color codes and if the board was damaged because they changed the wiring it’s on them.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely wired wrong. You need 4 wires to your stat R to Rc and Rh or R and Rc (it's hard to tell from the picture) bottom line is all three Rs go together obviously using the red. W to W using the white. G to G using the green. Y/Y2 to Y using the yellow. That's it! Get that blue one outta there. The other 2 conductor cable is for the A/C one goes to C and the other to Y/Y2.

Comment: Contact the repair company Lowe's and let them know the problem and that since it should be under warranty you expect them to repair it. It is also apparent the tech never checked the different cycles when he/she added the new board. Hopefully you did not change anything because that could void there warranty.